# Return timezone name with Moment's guess()

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I want to use [Moment's guess() function](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) to return the timezone continent (or country) and city as in their example:

```
moment.tz.guess(); // America/Chicago
```

But the above doesn't work. The returned value is `CET`, which is something else. It's an abbreviation of the Central European Time, i.e. no continent-country, no city.

How do I use the `guess()` function to return 'Europe/Stockholm', 'America/Chicago' etc?

Answer (score 12):

This happens when the host environment (browser, etc.) implements the API for ECMA-402 but returns the wrong type of time zone in the result.  If you are seeing this with Moment, you can probably also get this result without Moment with the following:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

Presently, Moment assumes that if this API exists, that it either provides a valid IANA time zone identifier or returns `undefined`.  However, some environments return things like `CET` as you pointed out.

Ignoring bad results is already recorded as a feature request in [moment/moment-timezone#423](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/423).  In that particular case, the environment was an older Chrome browser on an Android device.

Comment: where does `Intl` come from?

Comment: @Pipo - It is built in to modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late to this, but I was searching for an answer to the same problem. For anyone else looking for the same answer, using the following should work:

```
moment.tz.guess()
```

For reference, I'm using both [moment-with-locales.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js) and [moment-timezone-with-data.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js), and just using the simple `moment.tz.guess()` will return the full timezone name for me, ie: `America/Denver` or `America/New_York`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to momentjs library documentation, you can do this:

```
moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/New_York').zoneAbbr(); // would return "EST"
```

Here's the reference:
https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/

Comment: That's excellent if I wanted the abbreviation, but I want 'America/New_York'. Any idea how to return the name instead of the abbreviation?

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood your question, Sorry.Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstimezonedetect?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `moment.format('Z')`, you will get `-05:00` or something. And then map it to CET or whatever you are using based on predefined map.