# Letting users choose timezone for scheduling system: Problem with returning today on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, momentjs

I'm having trouble with the scheduling system I am creating in node (client and server API).  My server is in UTC.

As I wanted my timezone to be consistent wherever the user was based, I suggested a timezone to the user based on their business address provided.  The aim was for the user to be able to view their scheduling details from anywhere around the world, and still see the same dates.  eg. User business is based in the UK, and they schedule a booking for 8pm.  Then user travels to Asia for a holiday, logs into the system, and *still* sees the booking specified as 8pm, and can use the calendar to schedule more bookings, which can then be viewed back in the UK at the Date specified when abroad.

This had been working well up until now.  I am saving the user timezone against the user on signup.  I am storing the dates in the postgres database *without timezone*.  When retrieving from the database, I am using

```
date = moment(fetcheddate).tz(usertimezone, true);
```

When I am working at server/client boundaries (and am expecting a timezone), I am using:

```
date = moment(receiveddate).tz(usertimezone);
```

This ensures that all dates are consistently in the business timezone whenever they are being used, with the express aim of all dates consistently reading as a moment object with the time always set to 00:00:00.

On the server, my business logic makes a lot of use of Moment add/subtract; isSame/isBefore/isAfter to generate new dates internal to the workings of this scheduling system.

Now the problem.  Occasionally, I need to know what the current day is.  eg. On the server, I alter a blockbooking by enddating the currently saved block booking, setting to "yesterday", and starting a new blockbooking from "today". .

Looking at the "alter block booking" scenario in more detail:  on the server I generate "today" by calling moment, and converting into the business timezone, using moment startOf('day') to remove time info.

today = moment().tz(usertimezone).startOf('day');

I then set startdate on my new blockbooking object equal to this today value.

Now, if the user is in the same timezone as the business timezone, then this works perfectly.  However, if they are working from abroad at the time in a different timezone, then I get the problem that my startday is a day out.

For instance, my current blockbooking saved info may have a start date of "2021-02-06 00:00:00".  I choose to alter this blockbooking on the same day, 6th Feb, when abroad.  I expect my new startdate to also equal the 6th.  However, using today = moment().tz(usertimezone).startOf('day') results in me getting 5th of Feb as my new startdate, which is a day out.

I can't rely on just using moment() to get the correct date, as the server is in utc.  The only solution I can think of is to pass up the browser timezone from the client using

```
moment.tz.guess();
```

But I'm not sure I can completely trust this call for such integral functionality, as it seems that there may be a number of bugs. eg. [Return timezone name with Moment's guess()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621427/return-timezone-name-with-moments-guess).

I'm sure there must be a solution for this that I'm not thinking of.  Perhaps my choice of using the business timezone to sync datetimes is a problem. I *think* that passing dates without timezones at server boundaries would work for the majority of functionality, and might simplify things, although I am not sure.  But I think I still hit the same problem of generating the "today" date on the UTC server.

Does anyone have any ideas around this? What have I missed?

**UPDATE: Upon request, my main question is how do I get the date value of "today" in server such that it is equal to "today" in browser.  This "today" date in server must then be compared against dates that are set to the user's business timezone. Or if you have an alternative implementation that circumvents this issue then that is acceptable too**

Comment: Sorry for my verbose question.  I'll see if I can adjust it. I'm essentially wanting to ask, 
"how can I get an accurate representation of today from server when server is in utc and user is abroad, and their current timezone differs from their stored business timezone" Regarding storing everything in UTC, my understanding is that when scheduling future appointments, you should omit timezone info when saving the date to the db. This helps with Daylight Saving.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/what-is-a-valid-use-case-for-using-timestamp-without-time-zone

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the solution is to generate "today" on the client, and pass this up in request without timezone info, and then add the business timezone info at the server...

Answer (score 0):

**How to design when users are from different timezones?**

1. Store datetime in UTC in your database.
2. After users signup, when they login to your web application, ask them to choose a timezone. This can be part of *Profile* page of their user account. Store this timezone in database for each user.
3. Communicate in UTC timezone with other services, e.g. web application.

---

**Example.1:**

**User** chose **UTC-8** as his timezone through profile. And, He is making a booking for **03-Feb-2021 20:00:00** (his timezone, obviously). Now, web application would send / communicate through API as **04-Feb-2021 04:00:00**, and, very simple, backend would store it as it is - **04-Feb-2021 04:00:00**.

Now, lets say user logs out and logs back in and check his calendar, now again, web application would make HTTP API call to fetch that booking and backend would respond with booking date as **04-Feb-2021 04:00:00**.

Now, it is web application's job to find out (from profile data, e.g. stored in browser localstorage or with session storage) the user's chosen timezone which is **UTC-8** and do the conversion and show the user back booking as - **03-Feb-2021 20:00:00**

---

**Example.2:**

**User** made a booking for a **webinar** (let's go with this example) which will start at **15-Feb-2021 14:00:00** in **UTC+8**. Booking is done using a web application, so the web app sends the event start time as **15-Feb-2021 06:00:00** which gets stored in **database**.

Now the user **travels** to a new timezone, let's say, **UTC+10** and updates his timezone using *profile section* which gets saved in **database** as well.

After updating *his* timezone, he checks his schedule and the web application (after conversion) tells him the event will start at **15-Feb-2021 16:00:00**, and that is **correct** for the **user**.

Because, in real world, the **webinar** will start at -
**15-Feb-2021 06:00:00 UTC** == **15-Feb-2021 14:00:00 UTC+8** == **15-Feb-2021 16:00:00 UTC+10**

So, no one is going to miss the webinar, people living in **UTC**, people living in **UTC+8** and those living in **UTC+10** are going to attend at the same *time*.

---

### Case 3, Local Events

While creating an event, let the **user** choose / mark an event as **local event**, and when they do it, store event details, **datetime in UTC** and **event's timezone id** in database against each event record in table.

To display this event in web app, you need to send the **event datetime in UTC** and **event's timezone details** to frontend. And, front end can always show the event in **event's timezone** no matter if user travels to different timezone in future.

Comment: I need to think on this a little.  For one case, if a location changed it's IANA timezone (not sure how likely this is), and the user updated their timezone accordingly, then storing UTC would result in different dates being displayed to the user for the future dates in question. eg. If the original timezone was +8 and new new timezone was +10, then dates could now be different at a certain point in the day due to being stored in UTC.

Comment: If the IANA timezone changed, then all of their block bookings (recurring events) would now be at the wrong time, and they would need to change or delete them all and start afresh. Because an 8am appointment is always an 8am appointment. I should add that this is a scheduling system for a physical service based at the business address. ie. not virtual. However, I do agree that this is a very unusual edge case that is unlikely to occur very often if at all

Comment: Yes, that's a problem.  There is also the problem of viewing historic data for invoices.  You need to know what timezone each appointment/blockbooking was for.  With my current set up, I just need to store the timezone info along with the local date and bind the values on db request, and again on the client side. You could do it with dates on the timezone entry, but that is starting to get messy.

Comment: This is a pretty good article on the whole process. Although I wish he went into recurring events properly.  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/