# Firebase server-timestamp differs from the correct time

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, timestamp

I am trying to use `firebase-server-timestamp` to show the user when he/she send their order to us.

The problem I encounter is, that the `server-timestamp` is showing a wrong time (e.g: Current time is 12:30, but timestamp shows 12:15).
How is that possible?

### Android code

```
data class MyTimestampPOJO(
    val date: Timestamp = Timestamp.now(), // wrong, 15 minutes too early
)
```

### Database screenshot (sending was at 12:50 and not 12:35)

[image]

### Writing data to firestore

```
suspend fun sendEmail() {
    val data = MyTimestampPOJO()
    FirebaseFirestore..getInstance().collection("orders_service").add(data).await()
}
```

### Reading the data

```
export const dbOrderServiceOnCreated = functions
   .region("europe-west1")
   .firestore
   .document("orders_service/{id}")
   .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const data = snapshot.data()
        const date = convertTimestampToDate(data.date)

        return Promise.resolve()
    }

function convertTimestampToDate(stamp: firestore.Timestamp): string {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-De', { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }).format(stamp.toDate())
}
```

I am testing this inside the `firebase-emulator`. The time on my phone is correct (even tho it does not matter, because the `server-timestamp` is independent to the phone-time, as it should be.)

### EDIT ANSWER

As both @DIVYANSHU SAHU and @MiniDev99 pointed out, I had several issues. First, instead of using

```
data class MyTimestampPOJO(val date: Timestamp = Timestamp.now())
```

one should use

```
data class MyTimestampPOJO(@ServerTimestamp val date: Timestamp? = null)
```

The reason for this is, that the second POJO-Timestamp will be populated when the document is written inside the database:

> Annotation used to mark a timestamp field to be populated with a
> server timestamp. If a POJO  * being written contains {@code null} for
> a @ServerTimestamp-annotated field, it will be replaced  * with a
> server-generated timestamp.

Furthermore, every function can have its own region (callable and event-based). Because of this, one should always specify the function region to their specific region (e.g my function region was automatically assigned to us, but I lived in europe).

```
export const dbOrderServiceOnCreated = functions
    .region("europe-west1") // IMPORTANT!!!!
    .firestore
    ...
```

Comment: Please also edit your question and show the way you are writing the data to Firestore.

Comment: I think I know what is happening, Your server is in another timezone and your phone is in another timezone, so when the server time is 12:00, then your time is 15 min before/after it based on your time zone. So you just have to add or subtract time accordingly based on the frontend timezone.  `https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079801/13139719` This answer talks about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the Firebase Server time and date rather than the phone's date and time,
cuz if you are saving the timestamp of phone it would differ since every phone would have a different time.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: I don't have a "ServerValue.TIMESTAMP". I am using FirebaseFirestore, which only has "Timestamp.now()"

Comment: Edit: I changed `val date: Timestamp = Timestamp.now()` with `@ServerTimestamp val date: Timestamp? = null` and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think I've seen this happen before and in that case (but I might be wrong here) I think the emulator/phone where the app is running on had the wrong date/time set. So Timestamp now was wrong as well.

Comment: I already checked it. The Emulator Phone has the correct timestamp. For example: I send the contract, the emulator time is 13:00, but timestamp shows 12:50.

Comment: Furthermore, the timestamp has nothing to do with the phone time, as both are independent to each other